# How do I put objects of different types derived from a common base in the same array?

Tags: c++, inheritance, array

I have two classes called `Player` and `Enemy` both inheriting from a class called `GameObject`, how do I store them both in an array of type `GameObject` while still keeping their own unique information?

I tried making an array like this:

```
std::vector<GameObject> _gameObjList;
```

and then tried pushing a test object in it like this:

```
testObject test;
_gameObjList.push_back(test);
```

but then it gave me the following exception error:

> Error C2664   'void std::Vector<GameObject *,std::allocator<_Ty>>::push_back(_Ty &&)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'testObject *' to 'GameObject *const &'   OpenGLFramework c:\users\name\projects\myproject\gamemanager.cpp    11

so basically it's saying that the types should be the same, even though my testobject inherits from `GameObject`.

Here is my testObject header file:

```
#pragma once

#include "GameObject.h"

class testObject : public GameObject
{
public:
    testObject();
    testObject(float xPosition, float yPosition, float zPosition);

    void Update();

    ~testObject();
};
```

There isn't really anything in the cpp file that goes with it except the constructor and update method but those are all empty at the moment so I don't think it's necessary to show them here.

I hope anyone here can explain me the proper way to do this and/or can point out the error(s) in my code. I just want to have an arraylist of all my gameobjects so I can add/remove objects easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use std::vector<std::shared_ptr<GameObject>>

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<GameObject>> v;
v.push_back (make_shared<Player> ());
v.push_back (make_shared<Enemy> ());
```

If you want your code to look more like you are directly using Player, Enemy, and GameObject, you can introduce typedefs:

```
using GameObjectP = shared_ptr<GameObject>;
struct PlayerP : shared_ptr<Player> {
    PlayerP() : shared_ptr<Player> {make_shared<Player> ()} {};
};
struct EnemyP: shared_ptr<Enemy> {
    EnemyP() : shared_ptr<Enemy> {make_shared<Enemy> ()} {};
};

std::vector<GameObjectP > v;
v.push_back (PlayerP ());
v.push_back (EnemyP());
```

Comment: When an owning pointer is needed, yes, smart-pinters are the tool of choice. But avoid shared ownership and all the associated complexity and cost until and unless you know it's necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Well, a [`std::vector<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is a dynamic array of `T`s, not of pointers to `T`s or anything else.

So, we need a way to somehow store heterogenous objects.
Well, one can use a [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) or the more efficient [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) if one knows *all* the options.
Or one can store pointers, preferably smart-pointers, which generally means [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) or if you actually really need shared ownership [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

Which alternative is best?
That depends on your specifics, look them over and choose.

Answer (score -1):

Initialize your player/enemy as your base type.

```
GameObject* obj = new Player();
```

You can now store it in your list. You need to cast it to a player object to be able to use the players methods/members. Look up the visitor pattern, very useful with this type of architecture.

Edit: do note that it's now a pointer and is heap allocated.

Comment: You might want to be a bit more explicit that the programmer now is responsible for managing its lifetime manually.